# E-mails of users which send comments to android market? How to get them?

Tags: android, google-play, feedback

Many of users complain about my products, however they do it without any details. For instance they only write, that crash occur on start, however I can reproduce it, because I don't know which device was used by user.

It will be great if I could send an e-mail, to specific users and ask about details.

Is there any way to send user private message or something?

Comment: I would create an issue on b.android.com (Feature Request). Link it here, I'd definitely star it.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. Roman Nurik told us on Google Developers Day'2010 that it is planned, but they simply lack resources to implement all this features. Just wait.

I can advice you to add some contact info in your application to let users contact you dorectly.

Answer (score 1):

No way to contact users directly. However you could use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to get more info about crashes

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a technical solution, but I have found that users of my apps have responded well to me just adding a note in the app description that I would really like them to e-mail me if they have any problems so that I can attempt to resolve the issue.